# Adding css class to field on validation error in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation, django-media

I am using  Django's modelform and its really good. How can I highlight the actual text box (e.g. border:red ) if there is a validation error associated with it. Basically what i want is to add a class (error) if there is a validation error to a field.

Comment: How are you generating the form html in template? Printing the whole form object at once or printing field by field?

Comment: I am looping through form elements and printing errors, field and label separately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about defining error_css_class?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows?

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error'
```

Comment: This gives class to container of the form field. What if I want to assign class to form field itself?

Comment: use custom form template in this case

Comment: @Myth: $('.error').find(':input').css('background-color', 'pink');

Answer (score 10):

To answer the original question.

You can add the desired class to the field in the view to where you are submitting your form and doing your `form.is_valid()` check. Not the prettiest but it will work.

```
def submit_form(request):
    if request.method = 'POST':
        if. form.is_valid():
            # Do something with clean form data
            pass
        else:
            # Append css class to every field that contains errors.
            for field in form.errors:
                form[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' my-css-class'
    return render(request, submit_form.html, {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Or to encapsulate this process you can override form.is_invalid() and put this
`for field in form.errors:` loop in it

Answer (score 3):

Expanding upon errx's answer.

Add the CSS

```
.error input, .error select {
    border: 2px red solid;
}
```

to specifically highlight the field

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
self.fields['field_you_want_to_add_error'].widget.attrs['class'] = "error"
```

Answer (score 1):

template :

```
<div style="color:red">{{ userForm.short_description.errors.as_text  }}</div>
```