# Adding a class 'is-invalid' to input form in Django

Tags: django, forms, bootstrap-4

How to add bootstrap class `is-invalid` to Django input forms (only if the form/field is not correctly completed).

My forms.py

```
class BasicUserDataForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'is-invalid'
    user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                                             'class': 'form-control'}))
```

My templates.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <!-- Label -->
  <label for="id_user_name">Username*</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-0">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
    </div>
    {{ form.user_name }}
  </div>
  {% if form.user_name.errors|striptags %}<small class="text-danger"><b>{{ form.user_name.errors|striptags }}</b></small>{% endif %}
</div>
```

**I try:**

1.)

```
class BasicUserDataForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                                             'class': 'form-control'}))
```

2.)

```
class BasicUserDataForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                                             'class': 'form-control {% if form.user_name.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}'}))
```

3.) According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows)

```
class BasicUserDataForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'is-invalid'
    [...]
```

4.)

```
.error input, .error select {
    border: 2px red solid;
}
```

It still doesn't give any results. I would like to get the effect that gives:

```
user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                                             'class': 'form-control is-invalid'}))
```

[image]

Comment: You should be able to it with your third method. Are you sure you're model is loading your custom form and not the default one?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My field intemplate.html  looks like in my question. I added nothing more. We have something like that in the documentation: `<tr class="required error"><th><label class="required" for="id_sender">Sender:</label>` It seems to me that this adds a class not to <input> but somewhere above. What I don't have.

Comment: Hello @MaddieGraham check this answer this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108023/16705219

Answer (score 2):

**Create a file, yourapp_template-filters.py
 and then place it in **templatetags** folder in your app:**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='add_attr')
def add_attribute(field, css):
    attrs = {}
    definition = css.split(',')

    for d in definition:
        if ':' not in d:
            attrs['class'] = d
        else:
            key, val = d.split(':')
            attrs[key] = val

    return field.as_widget(attrs=attrs)
```

To use it in a Django template, firstly add this widget in the top of the template, similar to the load static widget:
`{% load yourapp_template-filters %}`
And now you can use it on any form widget as a function, like so:

```
{% if form.user_name.errors %}
     {{ form.user_name|add_attr:"form-control is-invalid" }}
{% else %}
     {{form.user_name|add_attr:"form-control"}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@ehsan nnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16736500/ehsan-nnnnn)'s answer is great! I tried it, and it works.

I want to clarify and extend it a little bit.

## Initialization:

*Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/*

The app should contain a **templatetags** directory, at the same level as **models.py**, **views.py**, etc. **Do not forget to add **init**.py in the directory!** (as stated in the doc)

## Attribute declaration:

The code provided by [@ehsan nnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16736500/ehsan-nnnnn) is helpful if you completely override the attributes section. I have based my code entirely on [@ehsan nnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16736500/ehsan-nnnnn)'s solution and extended it to preserve the previous attributes.

**NOTE:** I am using Python 3.10.1; if you are somehow still using a version before f-string or do not like f-strings, correct it to whatever your heart desires.

Here is my solution:

```py
# templatetags\add_attr.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='add_attr')
def add_attribute(field, css):
    attrs = field.subwidgets[0].data['attrs']  # Accessing the already declared attributes
    definition = css.split(',')

    for d in definition:
        if ':' not in d:
            attrs['class'] += f" {d}"  # Extending the class string
        else:
            key, val = d.split(':')
            attrs[key] += f'{val}'  # Extending the `key` string

    return field.as_widget(attrs=attrs)
```

```
{% comment %} HTML template {% endcomment %}
{% if form.username.errors %}
    {{form.username|add_attr:'is-invalid'}}
{% else %}
    {{ form.username }}
{% endif %}
```

## Tested on:

- Python 3.10.1
- Django 4.0
- Bootstrap 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Meta class to your form and assigning the proper model. For instance:

```
class BasicUserDataForm(forms.Form):
  error_css_class = 'is-invalid'
  user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username', 'class': 'form-control'})) 

  class Meta:
    model = User
```